# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'method' and 'int'

Tags: typeerror

Hi I'm very new with writing code in python, and I came across with this type of error and I cant get over it. i looked on google YouTube and here but I cant find a fix for my issue.

I'm trying to divide 2 numbers store in 2 variables and save the result in a variable

```
pbb = 47600
ti = input("enter number: ")
tipbb = ti / pbb
print(tipbb)




TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-556315176358> in <module>
      1 pbb = 47600
      2 ti= input("enter number: ")
----> 3 tipbb = ti / pbb
      4 print(tipbb)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rodney, change line 2 to `ti = int( input( "enter number: ") )`